# How can I make sure every new project includes SafeNuget by default?

Tags: security, nuget, nuget-package, owasp

[SafeNuget](https://github.com/OWASP/SafeNuGet) (an OWASP project) audits a .NET project for vulnerable Nuget Packages from [this github source](https://raw.github.com/OWASP/SafeNuGet/master/feed/unsafepackages.xml)

There is a [misconception](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103512/396) that because the package has an old date, that it consequently contains out of date package signatures... creating a circular issue where people don't use or issue pull requests to `unsafepackages.xml`.*

**Screenshot of version history as of 1/17/17**

[image: Screenshot of version history.]

**Question**

- To address the usage and deployment issue, how do I ensure that all new projects leverage this package on `File:New`?

PS: I hope by asking this question I increase the visibility and viability of this potentially valuable resource.

Comment: SafeNuGet has been "marked as inactive over at OWASP" (https://github.com/OWASP/SafeNuGet/issues/16) according to it's creator. Their current tool is DependencyChecker. The next closest thing to SafeNuGet would be NuGetDefense (https://github.com/digitalcoyote/NuGetDefense).